# Adaptar elementos a la pagina usando FlexBox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Quiero adaptar los contenedores de la página a medida que se hace la ventana más pequeña. No sé por qué los elementos no se adaptan.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
}

#green {
  background-color: #baffc9;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

#orange {
  background-color: #ffdfba;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: #ffffba;
  order: -1;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

#red {
  background-color: #ffb3ba;
  order: -1;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

#blue {
  background-color: #bae1ff;
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-right: 0%;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="green">
  <p>GREEN</p>
</section>
<section id="yellow">
  <p>YELLOW</p>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="orange">
  <p>ORANGE</p>
</section>
<section id="red">
  <p>RED</p>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="blue">
  <p>BLUE</p>
</section>
```

Comment: yo veo que si se adaptan, pero lo que no estoy seguro es que si se adaptan como deseas o no. ¿Podrías [edit] incluyendo mas detalles sobre que comportamiento obtienes y que es lo que estás buscando?

Comment: Te explico, al hacer la ventana mas pequeña, de izquiera a derecha o viceversa quiero que todos los contenedores se sigan viendo pero mas comprimidos, no se si me explico. Por ejemplo si vas estrechando la ventana de un lado, los elementos desaparecen y solo los encuentras si mueves la barra a los lados.

Comment: Eso sucede por los padding y margin que tenés en section. Por más que vos lo veas como un "espacio en blanco" para la caja es espacio actualmente ocupado y por eso no vas a poder achicarlos tanto como quisieras... prueba quitarlos temporalmente y deberías ver que el comportamiento flex es correcto.

Comment: Quité las propiedades del section como tu dijistes y puse en cada contenedor el margen  . Ya funcionó, gracias.

Comment: Me alegro, voy a escribirlo como respuesta, si te sirvió.

Answer (score 1):

Eso sucede por los `padding` y `margin` que tienes en `section`. Por más que lo veas como un "espacio en blanco", para la caja es espacio actualmente ocupado y por eso no vas a poder achicarlos tanto como quisieras. Intenta quitarlos temporalmente y deberías ver que el comportamiento `flex` es correcto. Si necesitas aplicar el margen, puedes añadirlo en su contenedor. O mejor aún, hacer uso de la propiedad [gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  gap: 2em;
}

#green {
  background-color: #baffc9;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

#orange {
  background-color: #ffdfba;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: #ffffba;
  order: -1;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

#red {
  background-color: #ffb3ba;
  order: -1;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

#blue {
  background-color: #bae1ff;
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-right: 0%;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="green">
  <p>GREEN</p>
</section>
<section id="yellow">
  <p>YELLOW</p>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="orange">
  <p>ORANGE</p>
</section>
<section id="red">
  <p>RED</p>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="blue">
  <p>BLUE</p>
</section>
```